# Google Push Notification issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get the push notification through Google calendar services.

I am able to get the notification too. But the main problem is that i want to get the notification related to changes made on Google calendar manually but not through my project. I just want to sync my project with Google calendar. As we have some user who used to manage the event through Google UI.

Please guide me how can i get the proper response from Google that these things have changed on the particular event.